# Find all roots of $8x(2x^2-1)(8x^4-8x^2+1)=1$ such that $0<x<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials

Find all roots of the equation
$$8x(2x^2-1)(8x^4-8x^2+1)=1$$
such that $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: This is not a functional equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Put $x=\cos \alpha$, for some $\alpha\in (0,{\pi\over 2})$.

---

Then you get $$8 \cos \alpha \cos 2\alpha \cos 4\alpha =1$$

If we multiply this with $\sin \alpha$ we get:

$$ 8\sin \alpha \cos \alpha \cos 2\alpha \cos 4\alpha =\sin \alpha$$ so
$$ 4\sin 2\alpha \cos 2\alpha \cos 4\alpha =\sin \alpha$$ so
$$ 2\sin 4\alpha \cos 4\alpha =\sin \alpha$$ so
$$ \sin 8\alpha  =\sin \alpha$$ so ...